# How to install Semantic-UI in Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops

I am installing a pipeline, CI/CD a React Project but suddenly it wants me to select an option on my semantic plugin.

How do I force it to install the automatic?

https://prnt.sc/v5ogsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [document](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI#install): Semantic UI includes an interactive installer to help setup your project. However, we cannot interact with command line task in azure pipelines.

As a workaround, you can complete install Semantic UI step locally.

1.Clone your azure repository to your local.

2.Run `npm install semantic-ui` command in your project. Please refer to the steps about install Semantic UI in [this document](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html).

3.Commit and push the changes to your azure repository.